# Network Sniffer - I not seeing the TCP traffic which my IP send to the device. I'm using Wireshark Software

Tags: wireshark, sniffer

I not seeing the TCP traffic which my IP send to the device. I'm using Wireshark Software. I only see the TCP traffic which my IP receive from device.

Please, did many things, and no solution.
- firewall disabled
- antivirus disabled
- Wireshark updated (Version 2.0.3)
- WinPcap (4_1_3)

[image]

My IP: 192.168.0.111

Device: 192.168.0.240 Port: 9870

In my PC there is a TCP listening service in the port 9870. 
And running a software to communicate with device. It occurs even if I connect others devices

Comment: Have you tried to mark one packet and then select 'follow tcp-stream'?

Comment: Setting as you said, it only shows one log.

Comment: If you don't have display of any outgoing packet at all, you might want to read: [this](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/14075/can-not-see-packets-from-local-machine) and/or [this](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/27296/wireshark-only-capturing-incoming-packets), try the suggestions provided. This doesn't seem a programming question though....

Comment: Thank you Nacho! Solved unchecking "DNE LightWeight Filter" in the adapter, like in the link that you sent....https://www.dropbox.com/s/zo79dg2qlnu0hsj/Wireshark3.JPG?dl=0

Comment: @BrunoYuzo Great! Then I provide the [link](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/8100/win7-64bit-wireshark-164-only-can-capture-receive-packets) with a brief description for whoever stumbles upon this question.